# React undefined setState from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

I've two componentes: `Orders` and `FormDialog`, the first is father of the second.
I've trying to send data as properties from `Orders` to `FormDialog` as follows:

> Orders Component

```
class Orders extends Component {
 state={
    open: false,
    order: {
      address: '',
      client: '',
      date: '',
      estimated_time: '',
      id: 0,
      order_no: '',
      original_order_no: '',
      phone: '',
      place: '',
      position: '',
      status: '',
      team: ''
    }
  }
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormDialog open={this.state.open} order={this.state.order}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

> FormDialog Component

```
export default class FormDialog extends React.Component {

  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props);
    this.state = {
      order: {
        address: '',
        client: '',
        date: '',
        estimated_time: '',
        id: 0,
        order_no: '',
        original_order_no: '',
        phone: '',
        place: '',
        position: '',
        status: '',
        team: ''
      }
    };
  }
  async componentWillMount()
    this.setState({order: this.props.order})
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.order.team}</div>
  )}
```

This display `TypeError: this.state.order is undefined` when try to compile. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your render method is trying to render a FormDialog using state which isn't initialized yet. State will be **undefined** until you set it inside constructor like:

   ```js
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
           order: this.props.order,
       }
   }
   ```

Since you're just passing down a prop from the parent component, this will be enough to render the component without errors. This way you don't need to call **componentDidMount** or, in your case, **componentWillMount**, and can remove it altogether.

---

2. You're calling **setState** in an unmounted component, which will always result in an error in React. As its name suggests, **componentWillMount** is called right before the component mounts and you should be using **componentDidMount** instead to make sure the component is mounted before calling **setState**.

Also, **componentWillMount** has been deprecated in newer versions of React and is no longer recommended to be used in code.

[From React official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

---

Additional note, it seems to me that you have unnecessary duplication of state in these two components. Consider keeping the order data only in the FormDialog component since it will probably be the only component updating order data.

Comment: Sorry, it was an example, only the second component has that state the first just send the object.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's a doubt I had some time ago but unfortunately it does not fix my bug, it keeps showing me `TypeError: this.state.order is undefined`

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look, it should solve your current problem

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the help but it does not work, at least for me :). I think I'll have to change the structure and put it as a stateless component. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Then it seems you're not passing **order** properly to the child component, try console.log(this.props.order) in the constructor to make sure it's not undefined.

Comment: It's not undefined

Comment: Then I'm clueless what might be the issue. Take a look here at this pen, I've rewritten your code using suggestions from my answer and it works as expected https://repl.it/repls/GentleAvariciousPlans

Answer (score 1):

super(props), not super( ...props)
same for constructor

This link to the doc shows the proper way

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Just after the constructor, the code is still correct but after componentWillMount state.order is replaced by this.props.order which is not initialised due to the first error.

Comment: I've changed `...props` with `props` but it display the same.

Comment: Bruno, perhaps add some color to the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry my first answer :) will need more practice for colors

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid state duplication, you can make FormDialog stateless component, maybe even function component. Remember to use as many stateless component as possible.

```
import React from 'react';

const FormDialog = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.order.team}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormDialog;
```

Regardless, it looks like your TypeError error appears because you

(1) Typo, it should be a

```
constructor (props) {
super (props);
this.state = bla bla bla ...;
  }
```

or just

```
state= bla bla bla ...
```

like you did in Orders component

(2) Tried calling setstate before the component mounted. Change async componentWillMount() to componentDidMount() should works.

But don't worry about that, after you change the component to function component it shouldn't appear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can not make it a stateless component because as its name indicates it is a form and I have to access that data and a method to save the form in the backend, I do not know if you understand me?

Comment: is the error still appear after you fix your typo and change componentWillMount ?